# Encoding an image sequence with the interpolate filter

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to encode an image sequence but continue to get a slow, stuttering video as an output. I can't go above 30 fps, 30 Mbit, so I have been trying to smooth out the stuttering with the interpolate filter.

ex: ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i img%05d.png -filter minterpolate=fps=30 -vf scale=3840x2160 -c:v hevc_nvenc -b:v 30M -maxrate 30M -bufsize 60M Output.mp4

Does anyone have any recommendations on the best way to use this filter or alternatives? I'm seeing little change in results.

Comment: What's the native framerate of your sequence?

Comment: Have you verified that your playback system can handle smooth decoding of UHD video? Hardware decoding support also depends on your GPU/CPU capabilities. Not sure what the NVENC HEVC encoder does, but you might even end up with 4:4:4 video, which you may not want (use `-pix_fmt yuv420p` in this case).

Comment: My native framerate is 30fps. Slhck, I thought the same about the playback system, however, I didn't have great luck with changing the profile, level, etc. I'll try the pixel format next. Thank you for the feedback!